# how to use jquery after running "npm install jquery"

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm

Hi I use `npm install jquery` to install a jQuery for my project.but i find it is located in ***node_modules\jquery*** with many unwanted files.

but I just wana put ***node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js*** into ***static\jquery*** folder

what is the best and common way? copy and paste manually?

Comment: Do you use a build system such as gulp or grunt? If so, they will let you copy the file or incorporate it in a concatenated script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use npm to do this. In your `package.json`, add the following to the `scripts` key

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build:jquery": "cp node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js static/jquery/"
},
...
```

Then you can run: `npm run build:jquery`

You can add more build tasks to this section as you need them such as copying images and minifying scripts and css, then chain them together in a single command with `npm-run-all`:

```
$ npm install npm-run-all --save-dev
```

And...

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build:jquery": "cp node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js static/jquery/",
    "build:images": "cp -R src/assets/images/ static/images/",
    "build": "npm-run-all -p build:*"
},
...
```

Then run `npm run build`

npm is a great build tool and often bypasses the need for an additional build framework such as Gulp or Grunt. It can also handle file watchers and such to rebuild when things are modified automatically.